# Removing comment in ini file writen by ant when updating the ini file

Tags: ant, phpunit, selenium-rc

I have an ant file which updates the data in ant file due this ini file gets updated and at the top it has a comment as follows

```
#Thu, 07 Jul 2011 06:54:54 -0500
```

I don't want this comment as i am accessing this file by php using parse_ini. Due to this comment i get an failure

```
Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in build.ini on line 1
```

so is there any way so that i will not get the comment in ini file.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
<propertyfile file="build.ini">
  <entry key="build-number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />
</propertyfile>
```

this updates my ini file build-number by +1

Comment: Show us the target in the buildfile which writes to the ini file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Date Comment from Apache's Ant PropertyFile Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452122/removing-date-comment-from-apaches-ant-propertyfile-task)

Comment: @martin clayton - Thats not working for me as there is my ini file

Comment: Do you mean there are # characters in your ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin's comment points you to a way to remove comments using replaceregexp. (I was about to show you a similar idea but using move, filterchain and striplinecomments. But the replaceregexp is more compact.)

The other suggestion I have is that since you are editing ini files, maybe you should use a task dedicated to that, rather than using the [PropertyFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task. There is an [IniFile](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/inifile.html) taks in ant-contrib might do the job.

If the replaceregexp doesn't work for you because your file has other # comments in it and you only want to remove that top line, then try this:

```
<target name="test">
  <propertyfile file="test.properties">
    <entry key="key" value="value"/>
  </propertyfile>
  <move file="test.properties" tofile="test.properties.tmp">
    <filterchain>
      <headfilter lines="-1" skip="1"/>
    </filterchain>
  </move>
  <move file="test.properties.tmp" tofile="test.properties"/>
</target>
```

Output:

```
$ cat test.properties
one=1
# existing comment

$ ant
Buildfile: C:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\tmp\ant\test.properties
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\tmp\ant
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\tmp\ant

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0 seconds

$ cat test.properties
one=1
# existing comment

key=value
```

Comment: for this i have to add ant-contrib jar file and i dont want complication to user