# Remove first line comment in properties file in Ant 1.7.1

Tags: ant

I have the following properties file - data.ini with the content :

```
A=1  
B=2  
C=3  
D=4
```

I run the following code using Ant 1.7.1

```
<propertyfile file="data.ini">
       <entry key="C" value="5" />
</propertyfile>
```

and get the following output in data.ini:

```
#Mon Jan 05 14:21:53 IST 2015  
A=1  
B=2  
C=5  
D=4
```

I do not want the first line - #Mon Jan 05 14:21:53 IST 2015 to be added to the properties file when I run the code.
How do I avoid it?

Comment: probably a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452122/removing-date-comment-from-apaches-ant-propertyfile-task

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I do not want it to be replaced by a blank line. The other solutions mentioned also do not suit my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mention ini file, I would suggest you to take a take a look at
[Removing comment in ini file writen by ant when updating the ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610536/removing-comment-in-ini-file-writen-by-ant-when-updating-the-ini-file?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This a work around (i.e all the properties are copied to another file except for the first line and copied back) and it works. Would there be another way to achieve this ?